# Android auto-scaling doesn't work on emulator with custom resolution

Tags: android, manifest

I have an AVD with custom resolution 480x800 and it seems like auto-scaling fails even with  . Bitmaps remains small, attached to left top corner of Canvas. 
Auto-scaling perfectly works with any build-in skins on emulator. 
I using  
Somebody, please tell me, Why could this happen ?

Thank you

Comment: Are you creating bitmaps from resources or from some other place (internet, disk etc.)? What is API level of the emulator?

Answer (score 0):

Create an AVD with custom DPI, 240 for example.[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer,  boulder. It works the way you described. But now I have found that WVGA800 build-in skin accidentally ignores <supports-screens android:anyDensity="false"/> tag sometimes. How can I turn on auto-scaling programmatically ?